# Modifying format in goaccess

Tags: nginx, web, goaccess

I must use goaccess on a log that looks like this:

`176.6.24.77 - - [Nov 05 2020 23:33:42] "GET /fontawesome/css/all.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 28 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0"`

I'm trying to use the log-format option and I'm using the following:

`goaccess --log-format=COMBINED --log-format="%^[%b %d %Y %T]" access.log`

and I get the following error:

`Token '04' doesn't match specifier '%d'`

But 04 IS supposed to match %d, no ?
I'm getting confused here

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in v1.4

```
goaccess access.log --log-format='%h %^[%d %t] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u"' --date-format='%b %d %Y' --time-format=%T
```